# Fetching records using some unknown join

Tags: mysql, php

I have two tables:

```
1.  Users
2.  Ratings
```

`Users` table have columns i.e. `id`, `name` etc.

`Ratings` table have columns i.e. - `id`, `rate_by_id`, `rate_to_id` etc.

I want to display all the ratings in a table. I can do this very easily with a join but the challenge here is that 2 columns of `Ratings` table point to `Users` table and according to me join with only one is possible.

By using which `JOIN` I can join Ratings table to Users table in a single join query with both the columns (`rate_by_id` and `rate_to_id`) have the join with Users table.

[image: Table Structure]

Please add comment if you need any clarification.

Thanks & Regards

Comment: Please provide table structure.

Comment: Attaching screenshot in the question.

Answer (score 0):

I got my answer. Actually I was looking for **JOIN SAME TABLE MULTIPLE TIMES** which I resolved from here :

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/12562027/9573341

And for my specific question here is the answer:

```
SELECT
    ratings.*,
    by_user.id,
    by_user.name,
    by_user.id,
    to_user.name,
FROM
    `rating_table` ratings
LEFT JOIN `users` by_user ON
    ratings.rt_rateBy = by_user.id
LEFT JOIN `users` to_user ON
    ratings.rt_rateTo = to_user.id
```